# TFLite Interpreter: defining optimal number of threads

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I am running a quantized TFLite model (in Linux PC) for inference using XNNPack backend. I am aware that TFLite models may suffer high latency for prediction and i'm trying to optimize its performance defining number of threads to `TFLite.Interpreter(num_threads=X)`.

I made some trials using X=[4, 6, 8, None] and the best scenario was with X=4, but this doesn't make sense to me. How it is defined the optimal number of threads? And more, defining `num_threads` automatically works with multiple CPUs or do i have to use another library/package?

(other optimizations that could speed up inference are very welcome!). The model i'm using is a quantized google BERT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your target environment. If the target is a single or dual core machine and you're not allowed to use multiple cores for your application, you should use num_threads=1.
Otherwise, you may use more threads to leverage multiple cores.

If your target only has 4 cores, using higher than 4 doesn't give a performance improvement but gives only memory and context switching overhead. (Also shape of inputs are related depends on op kernel implementation)

Regarding the performance improvement,
usually integer operation is faster than float. So you can optimize your model to use integer operations.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization

Also if your target has GPU, you could try GPU delegate.
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu